# interface/implementation files shows up in new windows

Tags: xcode

I`m using "All in one" layout. 
When I press cmd + opt + up arrow interface/implementation files are switched in new window. How to do in current window ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open **Preferences** (Xcode > Preferences from the menu) and on the **General** pane, under **Editing**, check off **Open counterparts in same editor**.
[image: Xcode Preferences]